# How can I export/import workspaces in Illustrator CS6?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs6, workspace

I have a (custom) Workspace which has evolved over time into the perfect one for my workflow etc. Using one that isn't set up exactly like it becomes very complicated for me.

I found some info online that it's possible to Export Settings in some of the newer (CC) versions of Illustrator, but I couldn't find a way to do it in CS6 (or older).

There isn't any <kbd>Export Workspace</kbd> option in my workspaces.

**Are there any other ways to export a workspace?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although there is no way to *Export* and *Import* a workspace, there is a way to do it manually.

Navigate to:

<sub>(Replace `CS6` with version running)</sub>

```
C:\Users\%UserName%\AppData\Roaming\Adobe\Adobe Illustrator CS6 Settings\en_US\x64\Workspaces\
```

You can run the following command to open it easily:

```
start "" "C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Adobe\Adobe Illustrator CS6 Settings\en_US\x64\Workspaces"
```

And then you will see a bunch of blank file types named with the names of your Workspaces, you can then manually copy them out and load them in to the same folder on the other computer (or just save them for backup).

---

On mac:

```
~/Library/Preferences/Adobe Illustrator CS6 Settings/en_US/Workspaces/
```

---

<sub>This will work with CS5-6 not sure about older editions (but I'd assume that it'd work with 3-4 as well).</sub>