# I would like to back up my User Defined Swatches Library created in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, swatches

I would like to back up my User Defined Swatches Library created Illustrator. How can I ensure these are saved if something happens to my computer, my swatches don't show in the Swatches Folder in the Ai Application folder...

Answer (score 3):

Open the swatch panel and click on the libraries button on the bottom and then select **Save Swatches**

This will load a dialog to save your swatch file as an `.ai` file which can be loaded into any doc and added as a custom library.

---

You can also copy them into the preset folder so you can quickly access them by clicking on **User Defined**.

The steps are the same as [this post](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/109553/63979):

You just need to change the folder from `Workspaces` to `Swatches`